# Como registrar os valores em um array bidimensional?

Tags: java

```
Java
```

Ja tentei com dessa maneira abaixo mas não esta dando certo.
Retorna a mensagem de erro: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

```
    private double[][] salarios = {{},{},{},{},{}};

    public  void cadastrarCargos(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                salarios[i][j] = num.nextDouble();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Em Java o tamanho dos arrays são fixos, ou seja, uma vez criado o array de tamanho X você não pode adicionar mais elementos a ele. Logo, quando você cria um array `{{},{},{},{},{}}` você diz que todos eles terão tamanho **zero** de elementos.

É exatamente por isso que este erro está sendo gerado. Você está tentando acessar um espaço no array que não existe. A solução para resolver este problema seria você declarar quantas posições o array terá.

```
private double[][] salarios = {{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}};
```

Se você desejar criar um "array" vazio para ir adicionando elementos aos poucos, utilize um `ArrayList`. Com ele você pode criar quantos elementos você desejar sem precisar declarar o seu tamanho antes.

Veja esse exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList agenda = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            agenda.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(agenda);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela explicação @JeanExtreme002